# treepanels drag and drop default behavior

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, tree, extjs4, treepanel

I have two treepanels which I want to drag and drop between. I understand there is a plugin for this, however I want it to behave a certain way.
 In my treepanels, I am showing the root node of the tree, and then all its children. The default DD allows the user to drop items at different levels on the tree(i.e. sibling of root, child of root) where I want all items to be a child of root for consistency. How can I make it so that any drag into the treepanel associates the item as a child of the root and not a sibling of the root. 
Why:
For a user who doesn't understand how this functionality works, one millimeter in either direction can change the item from being a sibling to child or vice versa.

Also, I would like it so I can only drag away those children and the root can't be moved, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can listen to the 'beforedrop' event on the target Tree panel's tree view and achieve what you want. Something like this 
 http://jsfiddle.net/EYtnk/1/ ..
One of the arguments of the beforedrop event is the node being dragged. You can check if it is a root node of source tree and just 'return false;'

P.S: In the example, i just used the same store for both the trees.. so the nodes get added on either side.

Comment: This looks like it will work, but how to delete the old node. Also, how does this accoutn for dragging within a panel

Comment: As i mentioned i used the same store for both the trees. If you use two different stores for the trees it should be pretty straight forward for you to delete the old node from the first store because you know what node you dragged.. Something like firstStore.getRootNode().removeChild('draggednode').

And in the example i made the first tree as dragGroup and second tree as dropGroup.. if you use a config ddGroup: that accounts for dragging within the same tree as well.. and again you can add a listener for beforedrop on both the trees and verify the source of the node being dragged.

Comment: Question, how do I access the source of 'node'. I think I would need to utilize dropPosition also to account for where a node is dropped, is this correct?

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop-event-beforedrop 
Check the arguments being passed to the event.The 'data' argument has a view property which is the source view. (view.up('panel') - source panel). Why do you need the dropPosition? I thought you need "any drag into the treepanel associates the item as a child of the root and not a sibling of the root". So in the beforedrop event just add the node to the target store. The 'return false' will prevent the default behaviour of the event so you can do anything with the data that came in.

Comment: I need the dropPosition when I am dragging an item internal to a panel, so I know where to put it relative to the other items. Otherwise, when dragging form panel to panel I do want the above mentioned behavior.

Comment: did you even refer the link? 
Parameters
node : HTMLElement
The TreeView node if any over which the mouse was positioned.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But I'm trying to figure out how to specify above or below the node.

Comment: How can I, using the arguments to before render, figure out where the item should be put relative to the others?